# Voice Assistant tells "during" in the TextView

Tags: android, voice

Voice Assistant tells "during" in the TextView but this word don't exists in the TextView properties. In this code, voice assistant tells "during identification". ¿Where do I change this text? This is the xml file.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/dni"
    android:id="@+id/tViewNIF"
    android:labelFor="@+id/editTextUsu"
    android:contentDescription="@string/dni">
    <requestFocus/>
</TextView>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextUsu"
    android:inputType="text">
</EditText>
```

Comment: go to res-->values-->strings.xml   and  find dni  in that

Comment: The strings.xml "dni" only is  <string name="dni">identification:</string>. I don't understand why voice assistant tells "during identification".

Comment: What do you mean by "Voice Assistant"?

Comment: Voice Assistant is an accessibility feature Samsung's mobiles. For the visually impaired, Voice Assistant help with navigating around the phone. It's similar to Talback in old versions.